# How to append row into csv file through python with commas separating new row and previous

Tags: python, csv

So..In this CSV file When I append a new row through python it comes directly in line with the previous row. And the second time I open the code this error comes until I actually add spaces through the CSV file(in word pad) itself.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\mathew\Desktop\COMPUTER PROJECT - UNIVERSITY.py", line 300, in <module>
    NAME[row[0]]={'COUNTRY':row[1],'COURSE':row[2],'E-MAIL':row[3]}
IndexError: list index out of range
```

And This is the code snippet.

```
p=[Name,c.capitalize(),co,e.lower()] 
with open ("list1.csv",'a') as r:
        w=csv.writer(r)
        w.writerow(p)
import csv
with open("list1.csv",'r') as fh:
       NAME={}
       s = csv.reader(fh)
       for row in s:
              NAME[row[0]]={'COUNTRY':row[1],'COURSE':row[2],'E-MAIL':row[3]}
```

I think that this is a really stupid mistake...but I am new to coding, so is there any part of code  I am missing out.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should print the row object to see if it contains 4 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation, when they open the file they put a **newline** argument.

```
    import csv
    with open('eggs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in spamreader:
            print(', '.join(row))
```

```
    import csv
    with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
        spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
        spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

For the part where you a reading the row from the file, you should check if each row contains the 4 items you need.